How can I create a custom datatype using PL/Rust?
I have a custom datatype called order_number in PL/pgSQL. This datatype is performing very slowly in AWS RDS, so I want to convert it to PL/Rust, as it is much faster than PL/pgSQL.
SELECT pgtle.install_extension(
'order_number',
'0.1',
'Order number type',
$pg_tle$
        SELECT pgtle.create_shell_type('public', 'order_number');

        CREATE FUNCTION public.order_number_in(input text) RETURNS bytea AS $$
            DECLARE
                l integer;
                c text;
                ordernum bigint;
                suborder int;
            BEGIN
                -- Check if input matches either valid format
                IF input ~ '^\.:\.\d+:\d+\.:.$' THEN
                    l := length(input) - 6;
                    c := substring(input FROM 4 FOR l);
                ELSIF input ~ '^\d+:\d+$' THEN
                    c := input;
                ELSE
                    -- Invalid format
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid order number format in "%"', input;
                END IF;

                -- Further validation and extraction
                IF length(c) <= 0 THEN
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Order number cannot be an empty string';
                END IF;

                IF substring(c FROM 1 FOR 1) = ':' THEN
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'The order portion of an order_number must exist in "%"', input;
                END IF;

                IF substring(c FROM 1 FOR 1) = '-' THEN
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Order number cannot be negative in "%"', input;
                END IF;

                SELECT regexp_replace(c, '(\d+):.*', '\1') INTO ordernum;
                SELECT regexp_replace(c, '.*:(\d+)', '\1') INTO suborder;
                IF suborder > 127 THEN
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Suborder value "%s" exceeds the maximum allowed value of 127', suborder;
                END IF;
                ordernum := ordernum << 7 | suborder;
                RETURN encode(ordernum::text::bytea,'escape');
            END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.order_number_out(input bytea) RETURNS text AS $$
            DECLARE
                result bigint;
            BEGIN
                result := encode(input,'escape');
                RETURN format('.:.' || '%s' || ':' || '%s' || '.:.', (result::bigint>>7), (result::bigint & 0x7F));
            END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;


        SELECT pgtle.create_base_type('public', 'order_number', 'order_number_in(text)'::regprocedure, 'order_number_out(bytea)'::regprocedure, -1);
        $_pg_tle_$
    );

Could someone provide a sample of how to create a custom datatype in PL/Rust?
